# MPMoviePlayerController iOS play audio file issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

Hi all I am using MPMoviePlayerController to play both video (mp4) and audio (mp3) files. I am facing an issue when the view is removed form screen, the audio keeps playing in the background, video is ok. On iOS 4.3 everything works great, but when I switch to iOS5 and attempt to play audio and press back (remove the view) the audio is still pressent in the background. Is there something different in how MPMoviePlayerController handles audio files in 4.3 and 5 ? I am using the same code for playing both video/audio.

moviePlayBackDidFinish method, where I stop the player

```
[player setInitialPlaybackTime:-1];
[player stop];
player = nil;
[[player view] removeFromSuperview];
[player release];
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Is your moviePlayBackDidFinish method called via notifications ? is this method getting called when you press back while playing audio file ?

Comment: Yes I am calling it with notifications, and Yes it gets hit when back is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

use this code to pause the audio/video in the MPMoviePlayerController

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{

[mediaPlayer pause];

}
```